# Removing JS Rows and Columns

Tags: javascript

Good day to all. How can I delete a selected row or selected column?

I have a table:

[image]

It consists of rows and columns in which there are inputs, on the right opposite each row there is a button - delete the `**-row**` row, and below the bottom of each column there is a button - delete the `**-col**` column. Help make deleting rows by clicking on a button opposite a specific row and deleting columns by clicking on a button under a specific column.

```js
let array1 = [];
let table1 = document.getElementById('tableOne');
let rows1, columns1;
let tableTfoot = document.getElementById('tableTfoot');

window.onload = function() {
  let get = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  };

  //table initialization
  function createOne(arrayRows1, arrayColumns1) {
    [rows1, columns1] = [arrayRows1, arrayColumns1];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayRows1; i++) {
      array1[i] = [];
      let row = table1.insertRow(-1);

      for (let j = 0; j < arrayColumns1; j++) {
        array1[i][j] = i + j;
        let cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = "<input style='width: 50px; height: 50px; text-align: center;' type='text' class='firstTable'>";
      }
      //display of delete buttons on the right next to each line
      for (let i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
        if (i + 1 === rows1) {
          let cell = row.insertCell(-1);
          cell.innerHTML = "<input style='width: 45px; height: 50px; text-align: center;' type='button' id='delRowsOne' value='-row'>";
        }
      }
    }

    //add line
    get('addRowsOne').onclick = function() {
      let row = table1.insertRow(rows1 - 1);
      array1[rows1] = [];

      for (let j = 0; j < columns1; j++) {
        array1[rows1][j] = rows1 + j;
        let cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = "<input style='width: 50px; height: 50px; text-align: center;' type='text' class='firstTable'>";
      }
      //display of delete buttons on the right next to each line
      for (let i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
        if (i + 1 === rows1) {
          let cell = row.insertCell(-1);
          cell.innerHTML = "<input style='width: 45px; height: 50px; text-align: center;' type='button' id='delRowsOne' value='-row'>";
        }
      }
      rows1++;
    };

    //add column
    get('addColumnsOne').onclick = function() {
      let tr = [...table1.querySelectorAll('tr')];

      array1.forEach(function(r, i) {
        r[r.length] = i + r.length;
        let cell = tr[i].insertCell(columns1);
        cell.innerHTML = "<input style='width: 50px; height: 50px; text-align: center;' type='text' class='firstTable'>";
      });
      columns1++;

      let columnButtonFirstTable = document.getElementById('columnButtonFirstTable');
      columnButtonFirstTable.style.marginLeft = columnButtonFirstTable.offsetLeft + 37 + 'px';

      //add buttons delete to bottom line
      let tr1 = [...tableTfoot.querySelectorAll('tr')];
      array1.forEach(function(r, i) {
        r[r.length] = i + r.length;
        let cell = tr1[i].insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = "<input id='delColumnsOne' type='button' value='-col' style='width: 50px;'>";
      });
      columns1++;
    };

    //row delete buttons
    get('delRowsOne').onclick = function() {
      //
    };

    //column delete buttons
    get('delColumnsOne').onclick = function() {
      //
    };
  }

  createOne(2, 2);
};
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
  <div class="col-lg-12" id="columnButtonFirstTable" style="margin-left: 158px;">
    <input id="addColumnsOne" type="button" value="+" style="width: 30px;" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <table id="tableOne" style="margin-left:53px;"></table>
    <table id="tableTfoot" style="margin-left:21px;">
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td><input id="addRowsOne" type="button" value="+" style="width: 30px;" /></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="-col" style="width: 50px;" id="delColumnsOne" /></td>
          <td><input type="button" value="-col" style="width: 50px;" id="delColumnsOne" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Delete lines:**

```
get('delRowsOne').onclick = function() {
    //
};
```

**Removing columns:**

```
get('delColumnsOne').onclick = function() {
    //
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a few things on your code, like using a class instead of an id to get more than one button, also I add the inputs by creating an input element and adding the selection listener there, here you can see how it ended up looking for me, maybe you can give it a try!

```
  let array1 = []
  let table1 = document.getElementById('tableOne')
  let rows1, columns1
  let tableTfoot = document.getElementById('tableTfoot')

  window.onload = function() {
    let get = function(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id)
    }

    //table initialization
    function createOne(arrayRows1, arrayColumns1) {
      ;[rows1, columns1] = [arrayRows1, arrayColumns1]

      for (let i = 0; i < arrayRows1; i++) {
        array1[i] = []
        let row = table1.insertRow(-1)

        for (let j = 0; j < arrayColumns1; j++) {
          array1[i][j] = i + j
          let cell = row.insertCell(-1)
          cell.innerHTML =
            "<input style='width: 50px; height: 50px; text-align: center;' type='text' class='firstTable'>"
        }
        //display of delete buttons on the right next to each line
        for (let i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
          if (i + 1 === rows1) {
            let cell = row.insertCell(-1)
            cell.innerHTML =
              "<input style='width: 45px; height: 50px; text-align: center;' type='button' class='delRowsOne' value='-row'>"
          }
        }
      }

      //add line
      get('addRowsOne').onclick = function() {
        let row = table1.insertRow(rows1 - 1)
        array1[rows1] = []

        for (let j = 0; j < columns1; j++) {
          array1[rows1][j] = rows1 + j
          let cell = row.insertCell(-1)
          cell.innerHTML =
            "<input style='width: 50px; height: 50px; text-align: center;' type='text' class='firstTable'>"
        }
        //display of delete buttons on the right next to each line
        for (let i = 0; i < rows1; i++) {
          if (i + 1 === rows1) {
            let cell = row.insertCell(-1)
            let input = document.createElement('input')
            input.style = 'width: 45px; height: 50px; text-align: center;'
            input.type = 'button'
            input.class = 'delRowsOne'
            input.value = '-row'
            input.addEventListener('click', deleteRow)
            cell.appendChild(input)
          }
        }
        rows1++
      }

      //add column
      get('addColumnsOne').onclick = function() {
        let tr = [...table1.querySelectorAll('tr')]

        array1.forEach(function(r, i) {
          r[r.length] = i + r.length
          let cell = tr[i].insertCell(columns1)
          cell.innerHTML =
            "<input style='width: 50px; height: 50px; text-align: center;' type='text' class='firstTable'>"
        })
        columns1++

        let columnButtonFirstTable = document.getElementById(
          'columnButtonFirstTable'
        )
        columnButtonFirstTable.style.marginLeft =
          columnButtonFirstTable.offsetLeft + 37 + 'px'

        //add buttons delete to bottom line
        let tr1 = [...tableTfoot.querySelectorAll('tr')]
        array1.forEach(function(r, i) {
          r[r.length] = i + r.length
          let cell = tr1[i].insertCell(-1)
          let input = document.createElement('input')
          input.style = 'width: 45px;'
          input.type = 'button'
          input.class = 'delColumnsOne'
          input.value = '-col'
          input.addEventListener('click', deleteColumn)
          cell.appendChild(input)
        })
        columns1++
      }

      function deleteRow() {
        const whereRowIs = this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
        whereRowIs.removeChild(this.parentElement.parentElement)
        rows1--
      }

      function deleteColumn() {
        const whereColumnIs = this.parentElement.parentElement
        const allTds = whereColumnIs.querySelectorAll('td')
        const position = Array.from(allTds).indexOf(this.parentElement) - 1
        let rows = table1.querySelectorAll('tr')
        rows.forEach(row => {
          let tdsInRow = row.querySelectorAll('td')
          row.removeChild(tdsInRow[position])
        })

        whereColumnIs.removeChild(this.parentElement)
        columns1--
      }

      //row delete buttons
      //Need to add to all elements
      const delRowButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delRowsOne')
      delRowButtons.forEach(delRowButton =>
        delRowButton.addEventListener('click', deleteRow)
      )

      //column delete buttons
      const delColButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delColumnsOne')
      delColButtons.forEach(delColButton =>
        delColButton.addEventListener('click', deleteColumn)
      )
    }

    createOne(2, 2)
  }
```

The most important parts are where you add a new input on create column or create row and also the delete functions.

Comment: You also have an error when you add columns, the code still works but you  can see an error on the console, you should check that